# mozilla equivalent for -webkit-gradient

Tags: firefox, css

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, rgba(255,255,255,.1)));
```

Whats its equivalent in mozilla firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`-moz-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient) perhaps? Try:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%, white 75%)
```

This may also help: http://www.broken-links.com/tests/gradients/

Comment: yes sure its -moz-linear-gradient, but what will be inside ()?

Comment: Answer updated - the gradient you give seems to be no gradient at all, dividing the background into two colors (transparent and white). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes its transparent to white gradient, based on background-color. But your code is not working, I am not sure how to specify rgba for mozilla.

Comment: Works for me. Did you try it as a value for background?

Comment: Try #00000000 instead of the rgba(...) value i gave.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out to help you generate cross-browser based gradients:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I found this site from microsoft to be the most helpful -

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html