# -webkit-gradient is not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css

The below css code is not working in mozilla where as it's working perfectly in chrome.

CSS:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #f2f1e6), color-stop(41%, #F3F2EA), color-stop(59%, #F7F6F5), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mozilla equivalent for -webkit-gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843243/mozilla-equivalent-for-webkit-gradient)

Answer (score 3):

`-webkit` vendor prefix is meant for webkit based browsers like Safari and Chrome and not Mozilla Firefox.

Mozilla uses `-moz` vendor prefix.

Use [-moz-linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-`  is for webkit browsers like chrome,safari etc.

For mozilla you need to use `-moz-`
These links will be helpful

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit
```

Is a vendor prefix, used for functionality that is not yet finalised and may not be consistent in its interface across all browsers. Chrome is webkit browser, as is Safari.

```
-moz
```

Is the vendor prefix used by Firefox and any other Gecko-based browsers. You will need to have both -moz-gradient and -webkit-gradient for them to work in both browsers. There may be others as well, and the arguments for specifying the gradient may need to be formatted differently.

Comment: Mozilla used and uses a different gradient syntax than WebKit from the start. `linear-gradient` is the standard now, and uses still different syntax inside the parentheses.